# Running C simulations on EC2

Tags: c, amazon-ec2, starcluster

I've been running parallel, independent simulations on a SGE cluster and would like to transition to using EC2. I've been looking at the documentation for StarCluster but, due to my inexperience, I'm still missing a few things.

1) My code is written in C and uses GSL -- do I need to install GSL on the virtual machines and compile there, or can I precompile the code? Are there any tutorials that cover this exact usage of EC2?

2) I need to run maybe 10,000 CPU hours of code, but I could easily set this up as many short instances or fewer, longer jobs. Given these requirements, is EC2 really the best choice? If so, is StarCluster the best interface for my needs?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create an AMI (basically an image of your virtual machine) with all your dependencies installed. Then all you need to do is configure job specific parameters at launch.
2. You can run as many instances as you want on ec2. You may be able to take advantage of spot instances to save money (all you need to be able to tolerate is the instance getting shutdown if the price exceeds your bid.)

Comment: Thanks -- could you expand a bit more on how I would go about modifying an existing AMI to add GSL, then deploy it?